# Mercurial - commit and then pull new changes creates multiple heads

Tags: mercurial, atlassian-sourcetree

How do I tell mercurial to merge automatically when I pull even if I have committed changes that have not been pushed yet?

When I commit and then pull new changes, I get two heads.

Git seems to do this by default, so I'm hoping it's a setting somewhere. I am using SourceTree as my GUI for mercurial.

Answer (score 1):

Merging **is** coding and you should really question your decision to do it automatically.  With git the common advice is to use the `--ff-only` option for `git pull` which tells git to only do the merge if it's a "fast forward" which is to say "not really a merge at all with no local changes"

In either git or Mercurial most people are to the point where they prefer `--rebase` instead of auto-merging.  It modifies your local work to append it to the end of the work you just pulled down and saves you the creation of a new merge changeset.

If you absolutely want to auto-merge in Mercurial the command is `hg fetch` but you have to enable it in the `[extensions]` section of your `~/.hgrc` because it's just a bad idea that it's disabled by default (but does ship w/ Mercurial so there's nothing to install).

Comment: If someone has pushed, why wouldn't I want to auto merge their changes? If I was worried about my code being tainted I would use a different branch

Comment: Even if you use a separate branch you're still merging at some point.  That's a code-modifying act so the oft heard opinion is that it should be an explicit act.  I'm not saying you're a bad person, just letting you know why it's not the default action of 'pull' and why `--ff-only` is so popular in git circles.

Comment: Fair enough. I did realize later that I can run hg merge and it will merge the multiple heads, so it's less of an issue now. Thanks for your comments.

Comment: Is there a way to auto pull before a commit and auto-push is made?